# Jekyll: Why do I need to configure Jekyll to keep these two min.js.map files?

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I'm adapting a theme to work with Jekyll. It uses several JS files:

```
js
├── bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js
├── bootstrap.min.js
├── jquery-1.12.4.min.js
├── jquery.countdown.min.js
├── jquery.flexslider-min.js
├── jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
├── placeholders.min.js
├── script.js
├── smooth-scroll.js
├── typeanimation.js
└── typed.min.js
```

When navigating to pages, I noticed the following error in the console:

```
[2019-02-17 18:22:48] ERROR `/js/bootstrap.min.js.map' not found.
[2019-02-17 18:22:48] ERROR `/js/typed.min.js.map' not found.
```

Nowhere in my project have I created any such files. I found that if I added the following to my config file, the error would go away:

```
keep_files:
  - js/typed.min.js.map
  - js/bootstrap.min.js.map
```

But I'm still in the dark. The files do not exist anywhere in my project directory. What are they and why do I have to instruct Jekyll to 'keep' them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map files are used by the console and html inspector. They help the developers to debug scripts and styles which are minified. You don't need to deploy them if you don't want to. However, you may want to keep them in development if you have trouble troubleshooting your bootstrap.min.js or typed.min.js.

To get rid of the errors, you need to update the source files by removing references to the map files or add the map file. Your choice but bear in mind that depending on your set up, if you're installing bootstrap (for example) as an NPM dependency, then, updating the source file will be overwritten if you update the package through `npm`.